# How to clone an Azure App Service max limit exceeded

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

When trying to clone an app on Azure that is +20GB in size I get this error:

Storage size '20' GB of source web app '....' exceeds cloning limit. Cloning supports a maximum storage size of '10' GB

What we are trying to do is create a clone of our live system into a test/devel enviroment.

The error is pretty clear, but now how can I create a duplicate of this app?
One option is download all to local, create an new app an upload again. But this is a bit tedious and slow. Even more if we need to do this from time to time.
The idea for me would be to restore this test environment every couple days to have updated version to play with without affecting the live site.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you don't need to download/upload files. You can move files into Azure storage, copy app, then copy files back.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has asked the same question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca9f198f-2d33-42a9-9c6e-e5df501f64a0/azure-web-app-backup-exceeded-max-size-of-10-gb?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) pointing to a change request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/10036335-increase-the-size-limitation-of-backups-from-10gb). As a response Azure created a new snapshot feature that has no size limitation on the backup. You can find this option when activating the "Backups" setting in Azure App Service. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/07/introducing-restore-from-snapshots-preview/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-restore-snapshots) for screenshots and what the limitations are of this solution.

Comment: Do you know if this solution will allow to restore the snapshot as a new App on a different Subscription? My cloning attempt was supposed to be the first step for moving the new site into a different subscription. Not sure this is possible though.

Comment: In some situations moving to another subscription can be done another way. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#services-that-enable-move) for more details on how to do that and what kind of restrictions there are.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about restoring a snapshot in another subscription and the possible restrictions for that case, so you have to try it first for some example App.

Answer (score 0):

yes take the backup web app manually using FTPS credential and launch the new webapp in azure.

then copy the data older webpage to new web app using FileZilla.